# Customizing Magento Sidebar

Tags: magento, customization

How can I edit or add blocks on the sidebar in magento

Answer (score 1):

Go to `app/design/frontend/default/[yourtheme]/layout` location  and create `page.xml` by copying it from the `base/default/layout` folder.

Search for:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="right" as="right" translate="label">
    <label>Right Column</label>
</block>
```

And change it to:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="right" as="right" translate="label">
    <label>Right Column</label>
    <block type="core/template" template="pth/to/your/layout.phtml"/>
</block>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a custom layout, you could use that to overwrite the block/"sub-block" by using a reference

<reference name="right">

<!-- Your customisation here -->

</reference>

http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts

specifically you might like to look at this image:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/images/uploads/term_reference.gif